# React Native: verificar qual checkbox esta selecionado dentro de uma lista de checkboxes

Tags: react-native

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema tenho uma lista de `checkbox`, e gostaria de verificar qual `checkbox` esta selecionado depois de clicado no botão.

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';

import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    ScrollView,
    CheckBox
} from 'react-native';
import Checkbox from 'react-native-custom-checkbox';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            checked: false,
            check: []
        };
    }

    _myFunction(value, name, checked) {
        console.log("Log:  " + value, checked);
    };

    clickButton() {

    }

    render() {

        let checkboxes = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            checkboxes.push( <
                View >
                <
                Checkbox

                name = 'checkbox2'
                checked = {
                    false
                }
                size = {
                    30
                }
                style = {
                    {
                        backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
                        color: 'blue',
                        borderRadius: 5
                    }
                }
                onChange = {
                    (name, checked) => this._myFunction(name, i, checked)
                }
                /> <
                /View>
            );
        }

        return ( <
            View >
            <
            Button onPress = {
                () => this.clickButton()
            } > < /Button> {
                checkboxes
            }

            <
            /View>
        );

    }

}
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz a solução em react para web, mas pode ser adaptada ao React Native.

https://codesandbox.io/s/649kry59y3

Espero que seja útil.

Abraços!

Comment: Cara valeu deu pra fazer em react native me ajudou muito